# Is it possible to programmatically identify the number of physical USB ports on a Lenovo ThinkCentre?

Tags: usb, fedora, libusb-1.0, lsusb

I have several **Lenovo** machines with varying numbers of **physical USB ports**. I need to **programmatically** identify the **number** of physical USB ports on each machine. The operating system installed is **Linux**. These USB ports may be either **empty** or **connected** to USB devices.

Even a suggestion of an approach to take to resolve this would be really helpful.

I tried lsusb, dmidecode but no luck.